# Angular Mat Stepper enable only active navigation and completed navgation

Tags: angular, reactjs, angular-material, material-ui

I made a steppers sample project with react.js and material UI. Link is https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-stepper-react-l2m3mi?file=DynamicStepper.js

I am trying to make the same sample with Angular and material, But I was not able to achieve the same functionality as react. can anyone help me with this?

Angular work link:-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stepper-dynamic-gpwp1x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

What I want to achieve in this sample:-

- Stepper headers:- In react sample I'm enabling only the current header and on select, I am enabling add the item button.
- Icons, I was not able to remove the edit icons.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to accomplish this.

---

**Disable add button:**

Add a template reference of `#verticalStepper` to your stepper

```
<mat-vertical-stepper #verticalStepper
```

Add a template reference of `#addButton` to your button step

```
<mat-step #addButton>
```

Then compare the button step to the stepper selected, and disable button if they do not match.

```
<button mat-flat-button [disabled]="verticalStepper.selected != addButton" (click)="addItem()">
```

---

**Use `[completed]` to control when the step is completed:**

Add a template ref of `#step` to your step `*ngFor` loop, then if `step.completed` will pass true to the `[completed]` input.

```
<mat-step #step *ngFor="let step of newSteps; let i = index" [completed]="step.completed">
```

Then in your `(change)` event set `step.completed = true`

```
(change)="changeStep($event, i); step.completed = true">
```

---

**Override edit icon**

Add the following to replace the edit icon with step index.

```
<ng-template matStepperIcon="edit" let-index="index">
   {{index + 1}}
 </ng-template>
```

---

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stepper-dynamic-qxh5qf?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html